# What is the name space of conversion.val in C#?

Tags: c#-3.0, windows

I have one text box in C# window application.And i wants to set a initial value of this text box is zero.
so i use conversion.val(textbo1.text) method.

But it gives a error in name space.

I use Using Microsoft.visulbasic; name space but it is not working.

So which name space i use for conversion.val().

Please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: use Microsoft.VisualBasic also read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9da280t0.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The namespace you are adding is correct.
Refer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9da280t0.aspx

Only adding namespace might not work, you will have to manually add Reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll.

You can add the reference as follows:
 - Goto the Solution Explorer panel.
 - Right click on References > Add Reference.
 - Select the tab ".Net"
 - Select Component "Microsoft.VisualBasic"
 - Click OK.

Now you can use the Conversion class.

Note: You can find Solution Explorer in the View menu.

Good luck!